# Single Text from two different UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have two UITableview's and if i select a one row in each table, the `textLabel.text` of that particular row should display in a single UIAlertview.

How can i combine the `textLabel.text`of two tables and display in one UIAlertView

Can anyone let me know how can i do this

EX: one Table view which displays A, B, C, D and one more tableView Which Shows 1,2,3,4.
This two table are from different class's. now suppose if i press a row in table 1 i will get textLabel.text as 'A' and if i press table 2 i will get textLabel.text as '1' now on the view if a select A in table1 and 1 in table 2 i should get a AlertView showing message as 'A1'

Code for reference:

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstTVContoller.h"
#import "SecondTVController.h"

@interface TwoTableViewsViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    FirstTVContoller *firstController;
    SecondTVController *secondController;
    IBOutlet UITableView *firstTable;
    IBOutlet UITableView *secondTable;
    NSString *stringTable1;
    NSString *stringTable2;
    NSArray * myArray1;
    NSArray * myArray2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *stringTable1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *stringTable2;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSArray * myArray1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSArray * myArray2;

@end
```

.m:

```
    #import "TwoTableViewsViewController.h"

    @implementation TwoTableViewsViewController

    @synthesize stringTable1 = stringTable1; 
    @synthesize stringTable2 = stringTable2;
    @synthesize  myArray1,myArray2;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        if (firstController == nil) {
            firstController = [[FirstTVContoller alloc] init];
        }
        if (secondController == nil) {
            secondController = [[SecondTVController alloc] init];
        }
        [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
        [secondTable setDataSource:secondController];

        [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
        [secondTable setDelegate:secondController];
        firstController.view = firstController.tableView;
        secondController.view = secondController.tableView;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if (tableView == firstTable) {
         self.stringTable1  = [myArray1 objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
            //call uiAlert, and place the stringTable1 on your message

        if (tableView == secondTable) {
            self.stringTable2  = [myArray2 objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];   
            //call uiAlert, and place the stringTable2 on your message
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"hi" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.stringTable1, self.stringTable2] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];    
            [alert show];     
            [alert release];

        }}

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}   

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [firstController release];
    [secondController release];
    [firstTable release];
    [secondTable release];
    [stringTable1 release];
    [stringTable2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

table1:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface FirstTVContoller : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *items;
}

@end


#import "FirstTVContoller.h"
#import "SecondTVController.h"

@implementation FirstTVContoller



-(void) loadView
{
    if (items == nil) {
        items = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"6",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",nil] retain];
    }
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [items count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%@" ,[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *stringVariable = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",stringVariable);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {     
        //Delete the object from the table.
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [items release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Table2:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SecondTVController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    int numberOfCells;
}
@end

#import "SecondTVController.h"


@implementation SecondTVController


-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    numberOfCells = 20;
}
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numberOfCells;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2.%d",  indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *stringVariable = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",stringVariable);

}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {     
        //Delete the object from the table.
        numberOfCells -=1;
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }
}

@end
```

Kindly Suggest

Comment: Make clear your question first..here people would love to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Naina: now i explained with example, take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not clear to me when you want your alertView shown,
but this will help you

you need to have a property for placing the text of your labels

so on your .h

```
@ interface MyViewController :UIViewController {
 NSString *_stringTable1;
    NSString *_stringTable2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *stringTable1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString *stringTable2;
```

on your .m

```
@synthesize stringTable1 = _stringTable1; 
@synthesize stringTable2 = _stringTable2; 
- (void) dealloc{
[_stringTable1 release];
[_stringTable2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

so on your table delegate

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    if (tableView == table1) {
    self.stringTable1  = [myArray1 objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];   
    //call uiAlert, and place the stringTable1 on your message
 }
    if (tableView == table2) {
    self.stringTable2  = [myArray2 objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];   
        //call uiAlert, and place the stringTable2 on your message

 }

    }
```

when you call your uiAlertView, for the message you can just show them togheter like

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.stringTable1, self.stringTable2];
```

Comment: Mako: self.stringTable1 is showing error as incompatible Integer to pointer conversion assigning to NSString from NSInteger

Comment: sorry you are right, is fixed now, your table is populated by an array so is actually the position of that cell on the array ;)

Comment: Hi Mako Sorry..i for get to say that this two tables are in different class let me post my code have a look

Comment: hi, is allright just pass the your string [from selected cell] from class 1 to class 2, and do the same as proposed on code above

Comment: Mako Sorry i am beginner, jus working things...can you put in form of code...it helps me a lot to understand

Comment: have your stringVariable in both tables as properties,you dont need the table delegate in your viewController .m if you dont have a table there, when are you pushing the view?, when you push your other view controller [if using a navigation controller], set the property for the string2 from the viewController you are pushing your view

Comment: post your project on github and I will check it, as I dont know what or how you want to accomplish it? send link and i will check it

Answer (score 1):

//Combine two string in one string on the tap of second table cell tap event...

**//Use following code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method..and enjoy...**

```
NSString *tempstring = [[NSString alloc]init];
   tempstring =yourlable.text;// your cell label...
   if (textField.tag == 1) {

    NSUserDefaults *stringsaver = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if([stringsaver objectForKey:@"stringsaver"]== nil)
    {
        [stringsaver setObject:tempstring forKey:@"stringsaver"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *combinedstring = [stringsaver objectForKey:@"stringsaver"];
       //NSLog(@"==%@",combinedstring);

        UIAlertView *alertdata = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Your Title" 
                                  message:combinedstring
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertdata show];
        [alertdata release];

       [stringsaver removeObjectForKey:@"stringsaver"];
    }
```

Comment: Nit: two Tables are in two different class's how can i combine them

Comment: @user1337800: I added new code use it and enjoy..but than after i suggest you to make your question very clear..it will help you a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell * cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // get here the instance of otherTableView.
    UITableViewCell * cell2 = [otherTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   UILabel *Title1 = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:1]; //for it you need to make the label with Tag 1
   UILabel *Title2 = (UILabel *)[cell2 viewWithTag:1]; //for it you need to make the label with Tag 1 
   NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[Title1 text],[Title2 text]];


  //fire the alert

   UIAlertView *alertdata = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Your Title" 
                              message:str
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertdata show];

}
```

Comment: were should i put this code in table2 class, find my code above

Comment: See, understand the facts first..you can access the tableView of secondViewController in firstViewController by importing the secondViewController in first and can get the instance of secondViewController's table view.But you can't really access the tableView of firstViewController in the second by the same process because you can't import the firstViewController here in second..(coz secondViewController is already imported in first)not at all a good approach...You need to find something else here..sorry if my answer is not useful for you.